# adding more functions in refinery controller and getting error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms, refinery

I am new Refinerycms. I create my own engine called "foodfind" `(FoodFinder\vendor\extensions\foodfinds)`. to become flexible I want to add more functions in client side controller `(app\controllers\refinery\foodfinds\foodfinds_controller.rb)` and their view pages.

I am trying to do this but getting an error `No route matches {:controller=>"refinery/foodfinds/foodfinds", :action=>"new", :locale=>:en}`

**help**

Answer (score 0):

Use `rake routes` to check if you have a route for that action. If not, then you have to add it to the routes file.